# Making one specific class of view controller auto rotate in a tab bar app, but forcing all other classes of view controller to stay portrait

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, autorotate

I have a tab bar controller with this code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    //NSLog(@"object type %@"  ,nil);
    if([[self navigationController ] isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
        if([[[self navigationController] visibleViewController] isKindOfClass:[SLImageViewController class]])
            return YES;
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

I need any instance of the SLImageViewController class to rotate, but none of the others.  I have done everything i can think of like adding return YES to my SLImageViewController and other fixes.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the code above from a UITabBarController subclass, or the UIViewController in one of the tabs? Also.. is this a right understanding of your question: you want autorotation to happen when a specific one of your tabs is showing, but not when one of the others is?

Comment: It is from a UITabBarController Subclass

Comment: I want only the SLImageViewControllers to rotate when they are visible.  All others should stay portrait.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you so much!
I didn't need to subclass UiTabBarController. I just put that code on the controller I wanted to have auto-rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could accomplish this by:

1. setting statusBar orientation to `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`

`-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear: animated];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    }`

`-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear: animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
}`

and rotating a view manually: `self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);`

1. presenting that view modaly will trigger `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method