# Rotate only one view controller in a tabbed application

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, uitabbarcontroller

I've read to many posts but I can't find a solution.

I've a tabbed application using storyboard. All the View Controllers of that Tabbed Application must show the content in portrait orientation, but there's only one viewcontroller (which is showing a video) that I want to be in landscape mode.

EXPLANATION OF THE STORYBOARD: TabBarController -> 4x Navigation controllers -> each navigation controller points to his ViewController -> one of these view controllers have an image, when I press that image, i've done a push to another view, the view that I want to have in landscape mode because I have there a UIWebView to show a video.

I'm unable to have all the app only in portrait orientation and the viewcontroller mentioned capable to rotate in landscape mode.

My app is also supporting iOS 5, so I know there are methods deprecated and I'm getting crazy.

I believe that in Summary > iPhone / iPod Deployment info > Supported Interface Orientations > there I've to check Portrait, Landscape left and right, and then via methods, enable or disable the rotations. I'm lost.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this if you push to the view as a modal. Make sure your application's PList file (under Supporting Files folder) is set to support all orientations and then simply add the code to the modal view controller to display landscape with something like this.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOr‌​ientation 
{ 
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft); 
}
```

Let me know if you have any luck.

Comment: It works for iOS 5.
I've also added a Toolbar with a back button to pop the view of the modal segue.
The code to pop: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Now I'm going to implement the code for iOS 6 because the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method is deprecated on iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

As i worked out for my App i advise you to use this solution.By using some conditions in the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method orientation type we can solve this.Just try with this link will help you.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021185/ios-rotate-view-only-one-view-controllers-view/15403129#1540312](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021185/ios-rotate-view-only-one-view-controllers-view/15403129#15403129)